# forEach with single document firebase queries in client side?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have different document id for every loop and when I query inside the forEach loop query is working but not pushing the obj into the array

```
  function getAllDonations() {
        donations = [];
        const user_session_data = sessionStorage.getItem('LoginInfo');
        const parse_user_login_data = JSON.parse(user_session_data);
        let TABLE_NAME = "donation_favourites";
        let get_requests_qry = App.db.collection(TABLE_NAME);
        get_requests_qry.where('user_id', '==', parse_user_login_data.user_id).get().then(snapshot => {
            let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
            changes.forEach(change => {
                var one_item = change.doc.data();
                let TABLE_NAME1 = "donation_requests";
                let get_requests_qry1 = App.db.collection(TABLE_NAME1);      
                   get_requests_qry1.doc(one_item.donationId).get().then(snapshot => {
                    donations.push(snapshot.data())                       
                });          
            }); 
            console.log("checking the data",donations.length)  //this length is not coming         
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you getting snapshot.data() check console.log(snapshot.data()) and give me answer.

Comment: Yes, snapshot.data() is getting

Comment: what you are getting in donations?

Comment: whenever I log donations it shows the data but I can't able to log, or perform donations[0] or donations.length or donations.map

Comment: show me your log data.

Comment: this the data when i log show empty array but when i expand that array it's showing like this


checking the data []
0: {category: "Homeless", category_qty: "11", category_shoe_size: "", category_size: "", category_type: "Money", …}
1: {category: "Homeless", category_qty: "11", category_shoe_size: "", category_size: "", category_type: "Money", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201704/discussion-between-narayan-siddhu-and-prakash-karena).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the files in use forloop but it is not recommended for large loop for small loop it is ok
if you want to read files parallel use forEach

You can also do it with `async` and `await` instead forLoop

```
await Promise.all(changes.map(async (change) => {
   var one_item = change.doc.data()
   let TABLE_NAME1 = "donation_requests";
   let get_requests_qry1 = App.db.collection(TABLE_NAME1);
   var snapshot1 = await get_requests_qry1.doc(one_item.donationId).get()
   donations.push(snapshot1.data())
}));
```